# Tab through XML documentation fields

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In VB.NET, you can move through the fields in the XML member documentation with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key:

[image]

This doesn't work in C#:

[image]

Is there another way (other than putting the cursor there with the mouse or moving to the field with the arrow keys)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of a documentation addin, [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) which has an optional mode in its live typing helpers to use tab/shift-tab to navigate between the documentation fields in a comment. I'm not aware of any other extensions that provide this facility (although that does not mean there aren't any!)

*(Thinking about why it's not in the C# editor by default: I imagine (purely a guess) it's because using the tab key to cycle through the entries means you can't enter indentation within the doc comments very easily - By default VB does a lot more auto-formatting of code as it is typed than C#, so perhaps VB programmers would be less inclined to use tab to indent their text so they wouldn't miss it as much as most C# programmers might(??). Or possibly the VB team and the C# team just have different opinions about this feature)*

Comment: That is a very good point about the indenting.  Might have just been a conflict of interest.  Still would have been nice if they had offered the option, however.  *shrugs*.  

And, yeah, I am guessing the VB and C# teams have VERY different opinions about a LOT of things.  :-)